# Why should we still use form element in html?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

With modern javascript (and js framework too!) and different ways to do a sync/async actions (POST, GET etc,..)  I am still wondering why would one still want to use form element?

Is it due to code semantics and actually "specifying" an area from which something is submitted?

Is it because form acts as a helper that "collects" (poorly I would say) data?

All of the above can be easily done in javascript, so I cannot think of any other reason for using form for submitting data?

Comment: For accessibility

Comment: Main use case of form element and for that many element is providing information about your html file to whoever is reading and to search engines.

Comment: Maybe rephrase it like "what are the advantages of using `form` tags" instead of "why should we still use"? Then it's less option-based. The question is very interesting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) that works using [progressive enhacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) continues to be best practise because there are plenty of circumstances where [JavaScript fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Aside from that, just because you *can* do something with JavaScript doesn't mean you *should* do something with JavaScript. Often a regular form submission will give all the desired effects with less work.

And on top of that, a form is a useful element to collect data with even if you do use JavaScript. For example, you can use a form element to populate a `FormData` element.

Forms provide semantic data to group form controls, this is heavily used by screen readers.

As mentioned in comments, some password managers use them to identify grouped login form controls.

Comment: Adding a specific example to why preserving standard semantics is _required_: Chrome's user/password/credentials autofill only works if the inputs are inside a `form` element that is _submitted_. It won't save anything otherwise.

Comment: Weather unobtrusive JavaScript continues to be best practice is questionable. There are a ton of web-apps that either do not support it or even cannot support it. There too few no-js users their support is very costly.

Answer (score 3):

one reason is if, for any reason, javascript is disabled / not allowed but an application still should work.

Comment: just with pure html... <form action="datatransfer.php" method="multipart/form-data"> is pure html and transfer the data in multipart form-data format with a http request on http://host/datatransfer.php

Answer (score 2):

It is also quite easy to make forms and send them via post/get in html. For me, it is sometimes a pain to do it in another language.